# Problem with Makefile recompile library file each time

Tags: makefile, arm, gnu-make

Hello I am trying to lean make by following a makefile template in this [repo](https://github.com/sferrini/stm32f4-template)

It is a project template to build for stm32f407 microcontroller. I have modified the makefile to include some standard library.

For time and resource saving, the standard library from the vendor should not be recompiled every time I run make. However, it is doing what I don't want it to do.

I am a novice about makefile.

Please take a look at my file and point me to the direction how should I fix it.

```
# Name of the binaries.
PROJ_NAME=project-template

######################################################################
#                         SETUP TOOLS                                #
######################################################################

# This is the path to the toolchain
# (we don't put our toolchain on $PATH to keep the system clean)
TOOLS_DIR = ../toolchain/bin

# The tools we use
CC      = $(TOOLS_DIR)/arm-none-eabi-gcc
OBJCOPY = $(TOOLS_DIR)/arm-none-eabi-objcopy
GDB     = $(TOOLS_DIR)/arm-none-eabi-gdb
AS      = $(TOOLS_DIR)/arm-none-eabi-as

## Preprocessor options

# directories to be searched for header files
INCLUDE = $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS))

# #defines needed when working with the STM library
DEFS    = -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER
# if you use the following option, you must implement the function
#    assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
# because it is conditionally used in the library
# DEFS   += -DUSE_FULL_ASSERT

##### Assembler options

AFLAGS  = -mcpu=cortex-m4
AFLAGS += -mthumb
AFLAGS += -mthumb-interwork
AFLAGS += -mlittle-endian
AFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=hard
AFLAGS += -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16

## Compiler options

CFLAGS  = -ggdb
# please do not optimize anything because we are debugging
CFLAGS += -O0
CFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -Warray-bounds
CFLAGS += $(AFLAGS)

## Linker options

# tell ld which linker file to use
# (this file is in the current directory)
LFLAGS  = -Tstm32_flash.ld


######################################################################
#                         SETUP SOURCES                              #
######################################################################

# This is the directory containing the firmware package,
# the unzipped folder downloaded from here:
# http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF257904
STM_ROOT         =../stlib

# This is where the source files are located,
# which are not in the current directory
# (the sources of the standard peripheral library, which we use)
# see also "info:/make/Selective Search" in Konqueror
MY_SRC_DIR       = src
STM_SRC_DIR      = $(STM_ROOT)/Libraries/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src
STM_SRC_DIR     += $(STM_ROOT)/Utilities/STM32F4-Discovery
STM_STARTUP_DIR += $(STM_ROOT)/Libraries/CMSIS/ST/STM32F4xx/Source/Templates/TrueSTUDIO

# Tell make to look in that folder if it cannot find a source
# in the current directory
vpath %.c $(MY_SRC_DIR)
vpath %.c $(STM_SRC_DIR)
vpath %.s $(STM_STARTUP_DIR)


################################################################################
#                         SETUP HEADER FILES                                   #
################################################################################

# The header files we use are located here
INC_DIRS  = ./headers
INC_DIRS += $(STM_ROOT)/Utilities/STM32F4-Discovery/
INC_DIRS += $(STM_ROOT)/Libraries/CMSIS/Include/
INC_DIRS += $(STM_ROOT)/Libraries/CMSIS/ST/STM32F4xx/Include/
INC_DIRS += $(STM_ROOT)/Libraries/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc/   


################################################################################
#                   SOURCE FILES TO COMPILE                                    #
################################################################################

# My source files
SRCS   = main.c 

# Contains initialisation code and must be compiled into
# our project. This file is in the current directory and
# was writen by ST.
SRCS  += system_stm32f4xx.c

# Contain peripheral library source file
SRCS    += stm32f4xx_vectors.c
SRCS    += misc.c
SRCS    += stm32f4_discovery.c
SRCS    += stm32f4xx_rcc.c
SRCS    += stm32f4xx_gpio.c
SRCS    += stm32f4xx_syscfg.c
SRCS    += stm32f4xx_exti.c
SRCS    += systick.c

# Startup file written by ST
# The assembly code in this file is the first one to be
# executed. Normally you do not change this file.
ASRC = startup_stm32f4xx.s

# in case we have to many sources and don't want
# to compile all sources every time
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)
OBJS += $(ASRC:.s=.o)


######################################################################
#                         SETUP TARGETS                              #
######################################################################

TEMP_DIR = ./temp
OUT_DIR = ./out

.PHONY: all

all: $(PROJ_NAME).elf

%.o : %.c
    @echo "[Compiling  ]  $^"
    @mkdir -p ${TEMP_DIR}
    @$(CC) -c -o $(TEMP_DIR)/$@ $(INCLUDE) $(DEFS) $(CFLAGS) $^

%.o : %.s
    @echo "[Assembling ] $^"
    @mkdir -p ${TEMP_DIR}
    @$(AS) $(AFLAGS) $< -o $(TEMP_DIR)/$@

$(PROJ_NAME).elf: $(OBJS)
    @echo "[Linking    ]  $@"
    @mkdir -p ${OUT_DIR}
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $(foreach file, $^, $(TEMP_DIR)/$(file)) -o $(OUT_DIR)/$@
    @$(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $(OUT_DIR)/$(PROJ_NAME).elf   $(OUT_DIR)/$(PROJ_NAME).hex
    @$(OBJCOPY) -O binary $(OUT_DIR)/$(PROJ_NAME).elf $(OUT_DIR)/$(PROJ_NAME).bin

clean:
    @rm -f *.o $(OUT_DIR)/* $(TEMP_DIR)/*

flash: all
    st-flash write $(OUT_DIR)/$(PROJ_NAME).bin 0x8000000

debug:
# before you start gdb, you must start st-util
    $(GDB) -tui $(OUT_DIR)/$(PROJ_NAME).elf
```

Here is the picture of the command line
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 160 lines of Make is not understood in a hurry.

Comment: Your rule for `$(PROJ_NAME).elf` doesn't create `$(PROJ_NAME).elf`, it creates `$(OUT_DIR)/$(PROJ_NAME).elf`, breaking rule 2 of the [Rules of Makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/).

Comment: `I am trying to lean make by following a makefile template` And this is a bad idea. The first thing to learn is always the basics. If there's no file with the name as _exactly_ written on the left of ':' then the recipe is always to run. Here make expects all targets to be created in the current directory, while they are either in ./temp or in ./out

Comment: Which file is the "standard library"?

Comment: @Beta The standard library of STMicro's vendor. Like library for GPIO, RCC... in this case, you can see those library in the picture attached at the end of the question. stm32f4xx_rcc.c, stm32f4xx_gpio.c...etc

Comment: @user657267 Thank you! I think I got the hang of it.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the pointer Matt. I understand some basic, just some of the problem like I mentioned in the question I don't know how to fix

Comment: `I don't know how to fix` Correct either recipes or targets, so that the file names match.